# Realloc doesn't work in a while loop

Tags: c, memory-leaks, realloc

I need help with my C assignment. The task is to write a program, which takes string input of unknown length. Also I need to separate words, that's why I use `char**`. Program stops taking input, when a special word appears. You can see my code bellow:

```
char **words=NULL;
 maxWords=1;
numberOfWords=0;
words=calloc(maxWords,sizeof(char **));
input=malloc(max*sizeof(char  *));

words[numberOfWords]=calloc(max,sizeof(char*));


while(stopValue){
    while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=' ' && c!=EOF){
        input[i++]=c;

        if(i==currentSize){
            currentSize=i+max;
            input=realloc(input,currentSize);
            words[numberOfWords]=realloc(words[numberOfWords],currentSize);
        }
    }
    input[i]='\0';
    if(strcmp(input,terminator)==0){
        break;
    }
    strcpy( words[numberOfWords],input);

    numberOfWords++;
    maxWords++;

    words=realloc(words,maxWords);
    words[numberOfWords]=calloc(max,sizeof(char*));
    currentSize=max;
    i=0;
    input=realloc(input,max);
 }
```

It works good, when I have only 2-3 words of input. But it fails when there are more. I think that the problem is with `words=realloc(words,maxWords);` this line, but I don't know what exactly.

Any help, please?

Comment: Why realloc words instead of wait to have full input? Why not just malloc a copy of input ? Where is the first input allocation ? why realloc it at the end of the loop ?

Comment: @RahulRaina WHy wouldn't `realloc()` work in a loop?

Comment: I highly suspect my *guesses* for the types and values of things like  `maxWords`,  `numberOfWords`, `currentSize` , `max`, `i`, `input`, etc., arel *not* going to line up with your actual running values. So... post an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ôrel He's reading input, there is no string to make a copy of.

Comment: You are setting the values of `maxWords` and `numberOfWords` after you use them in the calls to `calloc`. That's probably worong. You also got the allocation wrong: A pointer doesn't need to allocate space for itself, only for the stuff it points to: `Type *p = calloc(n, sizeof *p);`

Comment: @RahulRaina: `realloc` can work in a while loop. With `fgets`and the function you shall not name (`g*ts`) you are limited to a fixed line length. The Posix function `getline` can allocate memory while reading.

Comment: @RahulRaina He's not allocating every time, only when `i == currentSize`. He grows it by `max` each time.

Comment: @RahulRaina What are you talking ahout? It only returns `null` if it runs out of memory. This is precisely what `realloc` was designed for.

Comment: I don't have a problem with first realloc. It reads any large word. I have a problem with the second one.

Comment: @RahulRaina And when it does that, it returns a pointer to the new array. That's why you have to assign the result back to the original variable.

Comment: @RahulRaina that is utter nonsense. `realloc` is *designed* for exactly what its name represents. `realloc` can fail when there isn't enough contiguous memory to return a defined result, *just like `malloc` and `calloc`*. The only difference is `realloc` will, if needed, allocate a different buffer of sufficient capacity, copy your data, and finally free the old buffer, returning the new buffer address. Either you've no idea what `realloc` actually does, or have been using it wrong, but your claim "realloc multiple times doesn't work." is a blanket statement of complete bunk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `calloc()` should be the size of what the pointer points to, i.e. the pointed-to-type, not the size of the pointer-type itself.

For example, suppose you want to allocate space for 10 `int`, assigning the result to an `int *p`, any of the following would be proper syntax and exhibit defined behavior:

```
int *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
int *b = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
int *c = realloc(NULL, 10*sizeof(int))
int *d = malloc(10 * sizeof *d);
int *e = calloc(10, sizeof *e);
int *f = realloc(NULL, 10 * sizeof *f);
```

A pointer-to-pointer acts no differently. If you want to allocate a sequence of pointer-to-char, identical syntax applies:

```
char **a = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
char **b = calloc(10, sizeof(char*));
char **c = realloc(NULL, 10*sizeof(char*))
char **d = malloc(10 * sizeof *d);
char **e = calloc(10, sizeof *e);
char **f = realloc(NULL, 10 * sizeof *f);
```

Notice that not just the syntax, but the actual *code* of the last three in both of the above lists is *identical*, save for the pointer-type itself (the first is pointer-to-int, the second is pointer-to-pointer-to-char). That syntax takes advantage of how the `sizeof` operator (it isn't a function or macro; it's an operator) can be used against a *variable* rather than a *type*.

That said, `words` in your code is a pointer-to-pointer-to-char. I should be allocated using similar syntax for proper sizing. Either of the following will work correctly:

```
char **words = calloc(maxwords, sizeof(char*)); // right, uses specific type
char **words = calloc(maxwords, sizeof *words); // right, gets size from var type
```

Both do the same thing: allocate a buffer properly aligned and sized to accommodate `maxwords` number of `char*`, exactly what you would want for storing pointers to strings.

This problem is replicated again when you do this:

```
words[numberOfWords] = calloc(max, sizeof(char*)); // wrong
```

Again, `words` is `char**`, so `words[anything]` is `char*` and as such, should be assigned an allocation based on the size of the pointed-to-type: `char`. Either of the following will do so:

```
words[numberOfWords] = calloc(max, sizeof(char));   // right, or...
words[numberOfWords] = calloc(max, sizeof **words); // right
```

---

Ok all of that said, your suspicion that this is wrong:

```
words = realloc(words, maxWords);
```

is well-founded. The `realloc` function takes a *byte count* as the second parameter. You're passing a `count of pointers`, but not including the size of each pointer in the number of bytes requested. Using the syntax described earlier, this could be done as:

```
words = realloc(words, maxWords * sizeof *words);
```

or

```
words = realloc(words, maxWords * sizeof(char*));
```

Either will work, and now includes the size of each pointer, thereby calculating the correct number of bytes to request.

Best of luck.

Comment: words[numberOfWords-1] it was a typo. I changed code and didn't notice it.

Comment: `words = realloc(words, maxWords * sizeof *words);` is still wrong, because it erroneously leaks memory in the failure mode (when `realloc` returns `NULL`). It's intended to be used more like: `void *temp = realloc(words, maxWords * sizeof *words);` `if (temp == NULL) { /* XXX: perform error handling and return, break, exit or whatever */ }` `words = temp;`